# Send SOAP request to SOAP server having its WSDL and XSD

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a question about SOAP request.

I have both the WSDL and the XSD of the server side. I have to develop the client side, but I'm quite a newbie in SOAP area.

I read a lot of stuff: there are a lot of examples but I can't find a simple snippet which calls the server starting from the WSDL and XSD (of server side). I have both of them: I know I have to use them, but I'm wondering how to do it and, further, which is the best way to do it.

Can you give me some hints here?

Comment: Environment? Language? I think your questions too broad anyway.

Comment: Language: C#
Environment: VS 2017 Do you need other info? Please, tell me